# Permissions ignored for team site within personal site

Tags: permissions

This is SP 2010. I have a personal site (i.e. my personal site with My Host Site), and in that site I have created a Team site. In that team site, I have removed all permissions except for myself (full control), SHAREPOINT\system (limited access), and a "Team Contributors" group I created. That group contains only individuals, no SP or AD groups. Inheritance has been turned off for the team site.

When a member of my "Team Contributors" group shows up to the site, they have the desired Contribute permission. But, when a non-member visits the site, they still get in, albeit with "Read" access.

For me, the kicker is, if I use "Check Permissions" for that very same not-"Team Contributor" user, or other similar users, the response is "None". So how are they getting in with Read access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked it over at social.technet.microsoft.com and got the answer: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/f107b48b-e71f-4285-96a0-72aac769a972

Turns out that Central Admin "Policy for Web Applications" settings take preference, override inheritance settings, and do not get listed when you use "Check Permissions". Argh. But yeah, that's the answer. May it serve future frustrated admins well.